# Struts Validation Framework is not working

Tags: struts, validation

I have a date field and that should need to allows the dates of pattern MM/dd/yyyy.

In my Struts validation.xml file I have the following code

```
<field property="newEffectiveDate"
            depends="required,date">
            <msg name="required"
                key="errors.effectiveDate.required" />
            <msg name="date" key="errors.date.format" />
            <arg0 key="property.effectiveDate" />
            <var>
                <var-name>datePattern</var-name>
                <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
            </var>
        </field>
```

Even though I entered the correct format as 4/24/2013, it is throwing an error message saying that the date is in wrong format but when I enter the date as 04-24-2013 it is accepting it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> **date** - validates that a field can be converted to a Date. This validator uses java.text.SimpleDateFormat to parse the date and optionally either a datePattern or datePatternStrict variable can be used. If no pattern is specified the default short date format is assumed. The difference between using the datePatternStrict and datePattern variables is that datePatternStrict checks additionally that the input data is the same length as the pattern specified (so for example 1/1/2004 would fail with a pattern of MM/dd/yyyy ).

As taken from: [Struts Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/faqs/validator.html)

Try this instead:

```
    <var><var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value></var>
```

It seems to be a very common problem with close to 0 answers.

Comment: It does not work either with the following 
<var><var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value></var>

Answer (score 0):

```
<field property="pwd" depends="required,date">
       <arg position="0" key="pswd"/>
       <arg position="1" resource="false" key="5"/>
       <arg position="0" key="dt"/>
       <var>
         <var-name>date</var-name>
         <var-value>MM/dd/yyyy</var-value>
       </var>
</field>
```

the above code is working fine, so you might want to change `<var-name>datePattern</var-name>` with `<var-name>date</var-name>`. Do let me know if it works.